# How to insert NULL in database using Django

Tags: database, django, django-models, integer, nullable

I have a problem inserting NULL in Django. I mean i don't know how to do this.

I have function, lets call it `find_position`, then i have field in model like `position` (IntegerField, null=True, blank=True). This function inspect some html code, and if it match with some regex, it returns integer, but if it doesn't find - have to return NULL or None or something that I can put in database.

```
 def find_position(self, to_find, something): 
   ...
       if re.search(to_find, something): 
           return i + (page * 10) + 1 
    return NULL # or what i have to return here?
```

And i have this:

```
_position = find_position(to_find, something)
p = Result(position=_position, ...)
r.save()
```

Previously i user CharField for `position`, and returned '-' if not find the result. But i had problems counting total results, like position__lte=10 (because it's not `integer` and it messed up with numbers and strings `-`.

What can I do with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the function return `None` (or not returning anything, it's the same as returning `None`), in database it will be saved `Null`:

```
 def find_position(self, to_find, something): 
   ...
       if re.search(to_find, something): 
           return i + (page * 10) + 1 
    return None
```

Comment: Really strange. Tried this before, and had problems. Now it works! Thanks) And one question, how can i change all fields in table, which was `-` before to become NULL?

Comment: update the fields in the database directly with an update query like: `UPDATE youTable Set position = NULL WHERE position = '-'`.

Comment: Or you can do it with [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/?from=olddocs#separate-logic-from-presentation) in the shell. `Results.objects.filter(position='-').update(position=None)`