# integrity error - integerfield may not be null

Tags: django

```
class Incubator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    acceptanceRate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    funding = models.IntegerField()
    programLength = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    kloutScore = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

When i leave any of the integerfields blank, i keep getting an error that says,

```
IntegrityError at /admin/incubators/incubator/add/
incubators_incubator.kloutScore may not be NULL
```

I thought by putting blank=true and null=true, it would solve that problem?

Comment: Have you updated your database to allow that field to be nullable at the database level?

Comment: Check with __python manage.py sqlall <your_app_name>__ and verify in create table listing for Incubator, there is no "NOT NULL" constraint for your integer fields.

Comment: To anyone that came to this question looking for how to set IntegerField(null=True) to NULL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6291171/2271127 Basically use None. The database will convert None into NULL for you.

Answer (score 7):

it's because I added "blank=true" and "null=true" after i already created the databases.  I had to delete my db and then "syncdb" and then it worked.

Comment: or in Django 1.7, there are now built-in migrations

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post with a similar issue, so I thought I'd share the solution that worked for me:

In the original class in the relevant models.py file, instead of just using the constructor without any values like so:

```
 some_field = models.BooleanField()
```

.. I *instead* configured a default value of False:

```
 some_field = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

.. then after synching the database again, my problem was solved.